# Self Referential Puzzle - medium 2

Tags: code-golf, game, combinatorics, permutations

The following puzzle was asked in [puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/self-referential-puzzle-medium-2). This puzzle is quite hard to solve by hand because every answer depends on another answer. So, for example, a solution with all answers being A does not work because then the question 7 would contradict question 8, for example.

One of the answers there at puzzling SE suggested to write a program to test all possible answers and show one of them (if it exists). So, I'm bringing this to the experts :)

The puzzle consists in finding an array of ten characters (each one of them being either A, B, C, D or E) that satisfies all the following questions (where each character in the array is an "answer" and its index is a "question") **without contradiction**:

1. The first question whose answer is D is the question

   > A.  8
   >   B.  7
   >   C.  6
   >   D.  5
   >   E.  4
2. Identical answers have questions

   > A.  3 and 4
   >   B.  4 and 5
   >   C.  5 and 6
   >   D.  6 and 7
   >   E.  7 and 8
3. The number of questions with the answer E is

   > A.  1
   >   B.  2
   >   C.  3
   >   D.  4
   >   E.  5
4. The number of questions with the answer A is

   > A.  1
   >   B.  2
   >   C.  3
   >   D.  4
   >   E.  5
5. The number of questions with the answer A equals the number of questions with the answer

   > A.  A
   >   B.  B
   >   C.  C
   >   D.  D
   >   E.  none of the above
6. The last question whose answer is B is the question

   > A.  5
   >   B.  6
   >   C.  7
   >   D.  8
   >   E.  9
7. Alphabetically, the answer to this question and the answer to the following question are

   > A.  4 apart
   >   B.  3 apart
   >   C.  2 apart
   >   D.  1 apart
   >   E.  the same
8. The answer to this question is the same as the answer to the question

   > A.  1
   >   B.  2
   >   C.  3
   >   D.  4
   >   E.  5
9. The number of questions whose answers are consonants

   > A.  3
   >   B.  4
   >   C.  5
   >   D.  6
   >   E.  7
10. The answer to this question is

    > A.  A
    >   B.  B
    >   C.  C
    >   D.  D
    >   E.  E

The objective of this chalenge is to write the **shortest program** that can **generate all the possible answers** and **check how many of them** (if any) satisfy what every one of the previous questions are asking (the output of the program would be the list of the answers that satisfy all the questions without contradiction).

The original test can be found [here](https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/self-referential-quiz/srq-2/) (although it is irrelevant for this chalenge).

Comment: Add an objective winning criterion (such as shortest code length, most popular answer after X days,  or something of that ilk). That's a requirement for posted things here to not be closed; short of that, this looks fun.

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site.  There are a few things that need to be changed about this question.  1) in order to be on topic all questions need an "Objective winning criterion", that is a way to score answers so that people have a goal other than simply completing the challenge.  The most popular one is [tag:code-golf]. 2) right now this challenge is a bit underspecified.  Without clicking the puzzling link I have no idea what is being asked.  You should aim to outline exactly what answers must do to their input.  Test cases which you included are always welcome.

Comment: Is #5 correct? It seems the answer will always be A. And what happens with #2 if a set of possible answers has identical answers to #4, #5, and #6?

Comment: @GregMartin the way I understand it, the way these questions work is that they might have multiple correct answers but some of those answers might cause the other questions to have no correct answers and are thus invalid. If a question does have multiple correct answers that don't cause another question to have no valid answers then there are multiple solutions to the puzzle.

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken it's a step in the right direction. One thing you still need to clarify though is what exactly you want as output. Should the program output all 9765625 possible answers along with whether each works or doesn't work? Or should it output just the correct solutions? In relation to that what exactly does "generate and check all the possible answers" mean? What it mean to generate an answer and what does it mean to check it? How much checking are people allowed to optimize away? One extreme would be hardcoding the answer which you probably don't want.

Comment: I'm not sure that the validity check is objective here (making it hard to know who's won and who needs to be disqualified). How are we excluding answers that just hardcode assumptions about the problem? The normal fix to this would be to take the list of questions as input, but I'm not sure that works here because the questions don't follow a common structure.

Comment: Note: I found a slight wording difference between the source of this (the linked webpage) and the [original paper](http://hrcak.srce.hr/78211?lang=en) from which that was sourced. I don't *think* it makes any difference to the solution-set (which I believe is of size 0, yet ought to be of size 1 as has the question-set of which it is supposedly an isomorphism). Where this says "5. The number of questions with the answer A equals the number of questions with the answer (A) A (B) B (C) C (D) D (E) none of the above" the paper says "...(A) A (B) B (C) D (D) E (E) none of the above".

Comment: @0, @ais523 Thanks for the suggestions! I've made same corrections, maybe it is clearer now...

Comment: @JonathanAllan, [someone at Puzzling.SE saw that too](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/self-referential-puzzle-medium-2#answer-51152) (see the last paragraph of this answer...). Apparently this does not make much of a difference...

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken I am that someone

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh sorry! Just saw that... I feel so silly now...

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken the output specification looks good. The only thing left to fix with your challenge is with "generate all possible answers". I might be interpreting this in the wrong way but it sounds to me like this is an algorithm requirement which is a [non-observable program requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/10002#10002). Such requirements are [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/should-we-disallow-non-observable-requirements) in [tag:code-golf].

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pyth), 104 bytes

```
f!s[nhd-8xd3@.+d+3@d1nh@d2/d4nh@d3/d0!&/3@d4!-/d0/d@d4!-10x_d1@d5n@d6a4@.+d6n@d7@d@d7!+3@d8@ds/LdS3)^U5T
```

It... uh... takes a while to run. [Try it online... if the server doesn't time out or run out of memory.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21s%5Bnhd-8xd3%40.%2Bd%2B3%40d1nh%40d2%2Fd4nh%40d3%2Fd0%21%26%2F3%40d4%21-%2Fd0%2Fd%40d4%21-10x_d1%40d5n%40d6a4%40.%2Bd6n%40d7%40d%40d7%21%2B3%40d8%40ds%2FLdS3%29%5EU5T&debug=0)

Explanation coming Soon<sup>TM</sup>.  Prints all the valid solutions as a 0-based list (ten elements long in which `A` is represented by `0`, `B` by `1`, and so on).

This is a naive solution that can probably be golfed a lot.  Just wanted to get something out there.